# Amazon Cognito Profile information in AWS Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I have created my Amazon Cognito user pool and added few users. Added custom attributes in Cognito to differentiate between normal user and admin user. Exposed a REST API (for only admin users) to get the profile information of the given user using API Gateway and Lambda Engine to access my RDS DB instance to get few fields for that user from my DB.

I want to access the Cognito user profile information with the given username/subId from Lambda Engine / API Gateway.

I know with the given ID Token in API Gateway we can access the user profile details. But as a admin user I need to access details of other users with the given username from API Gateway or Lambda.

Kindly share, if you know how to get the user profile information from Cognito.

Answer (score 0):

You are not mentioning which technology you are using to execute your Lambda functions.

Depending on SDK you will get an context object containing lots of information or you can read out the environment variables.

E.g. for Java the Lambda function gets a [context object](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-java-libs/blob/master/aws-lambda-java-core/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/lambda/runtime/Context.java).

You could retrieve the identity from that one using:

```
context.getIdentity()
```

Update:
For Python it basically works the same way.
There is a [context object](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-context-object.html) as well. You can access it using `context.identity`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am using Python to execute my Lambda functions.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am using Python to execute my Lambda functions. Say, I am Admin user, I need to get the complete profile information about the user "James" from Cognito. How to query and get the complete profile information of another user in Lambda?

Comment: @Jay using the cognito api is different question check the [API Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognitoidentity/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html) and/or the [developer guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/what-is-amazon-cognito.html).